# What operation is required when I would take the 'inverse of a vector'?

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, lagrange-multiplier

I am working on brushing up my linear algebra knowledge and have stumbled over the following problem.

Assume we have $$Wx + \lambda a = 0$$ where $W$ a diagonal square Matrix, $x$ a conformable column vector, $\lambda$ a scalar, and $a$ a column vector of dimensions conformable to $Wx$. Intuitively I just wanted to solve for $\lambda$ as $$\lambda=(-Wx)a^{-1}$$ just before realizing that I do not know any definition of the inverse of a vector. So perhaps my thinking goes wrong here. Can you help me finding the solution to this linear system of equations?

The background of this question is a lagrange multiplier optimization with function $f(x)=x^T W x$ and constraint $g(x)=a^Tx+a_0$ ($a_0$ a scalar) where after taking the gradient of Lagrangian $L=f(x)+\lambda g(x)$ I am left with the equation in question (with constraint $a^Tx+a_0$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do the “inverse of a vector”. Following the hint, instead, you can multiply by $x^T$ to the left, getting
$$
x^TWx+\lambda(x^Ta)=0
$$
Now $x^TWx$ and $x^Ta$ are numbers (actually $1\times 1$ matrices, but it doesn't make a difference). If $x^Ta\ne0$, the solution is
$$
\lambda=-\frac{x^TWx}{x^Ta}
$$

Comment: Thank you, this solves the question for $\lambda$. However for the Lagrangian multiplier motivation, I suppose we cannot find $\lambda$ in this way since $a^Tx+a_0=0$ which cannot be solved for $x$ either. So the hint by @HHRugh needs to be followed more explicitly in this situation.

Comment: @tomka $a^Tx+a_0=0$ will have infinitely many solutions, if it has one. Note also that from $a^Tx+a_0=0$ we get $x^Ta+a_0=0$, so the condition $x^Ta\ne0$ is equivalent to $a_0\ne0$. Thus $\lambda=\frac{x^TWx}{a_0}$.

Comment: Okay, but this still does not help me to find the lagrangian multiplier since $x^T W x$ still depends on $x$. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @tomka Yes, of course. Why shouldn't it depend on $x$?

Comment: It should; what I mean is that, in the Lagrangian problem, I do not have a closed form solution for $\lambda$ yet, since $x$ is unknown.

Answer (score 2):

If $\mathrm a \neq 0_n$, then **left**-multiplying both sides of $\mathrm W \mathrm x + \lambda \mathrm a = \mathrm 0_n$ by $\dfrac{\mathrm a^\top}{\mathrm a^\top \mathrm a}$, we obtain

$$\dfrac{\mathrm a^\top \mathrm W \mathrm x}{\mathrm a^\top \mathrm a} + \lambda \dfrac{\mathrm a^\top \mathrm a}{\mathrm a^\top \mathrm a} = 0$$

and, thus,

$$\lambda = - \dfrac{\mathrm a^\top \mathrm W \mathrm x}{\mathrm a^\top \mathrm a}$$

Hence, the **left** inverse of *column* vector $\mathrm a$ is the *row* vector $\dfrac{\mathrm a^\top}{\mathrm a^\top \mathrm a}$.

Comment: It seems we may use a similar trick in the constraint $a^Tx + a_0 = 0$. We first left multiply $a$. Then we take the real inverse to find $x = - a_0 (a a^T)^{-1} a$. Then we plug into $\lambda$ to find $\lambda= a_0 a^T W (aa^T)^{-1}a (a^Ta)^{-1}$. Does this seem correct?

Comment: Ah no. $aa^T$ is not positive semi-definite.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work that way. Instead you should first solve to find $x$ (by using the inverse of $W$, provided that the diagonal has no zero elements) as a function of $\lambda$ and then plug that value of $x$ into the constraint equation to find $\lambda$.